# system.net.mail displayname not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, email

When I send an email, it shows the smtp google email account I used to send it, instead of
the specified email I put in my code.  My code is

```
MailAddress addrfrom = new MailAddress("info@Company.org", "Company Support");
```

Currently showing in Email:

```
Company A <(mygoogleemail@google.com)>
```

But, I want it to show

```
Company A <(info@company.org)>
```

I am using `smtp.google.com` with `mygoogleemail@google.com/password`

Whats the problem?  Do I need to modify settings in my google smtp settings?

Answer (score 3):

> When I send an email, it shows the smtp google email account I used to send it,

That's absolutely normal and it's how SMTP works. Otherwise you could send an email on behalf of President Obama and not just `info@company.org` as you wanted in your question. The email is always sent on behalf of the owner of the account on the SMTP server.

If you want to send an email from `info@company.org` you will have to setup an SMTP server on `company.org` and create an account called `info`. Then use the SMTP settings of this server to send your email.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google do this automatically.

They do offer a service to add additional email addresses to send from to your account (by verifying the email address separately).

Once an email address is verified on your account, you should be able to send from it as you're trying to do here.

How to add additional "sending email addresses" is on the Google Help [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370).

There's also a visual walkthrough of the process I found [here](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/configure_google_gmail_to_have_a_different_sender.html).